# Problem creating templates / template group in the CP

Tags: templates

Running EE 6.2.4

I recently upgrade from EE5 to EE6 locally, in the process of creating a new template/template group in the CP (by clicking on the Templates link in the sidebar), i suddenly got the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8C\xAC R...' for column 'template_data' at row 1:
UPDATE `exp_templates` SET `template_data` =
```

**Stack Trace**

```
#0 ee/legacy/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php(112): CI_DB_mysqli_connection->query('UPDATE `exp_tem...')
#1 ee/legacy/database/DB_driver.php(260): CI_DB_mysqli_driver->_execute('UPDATE `exp_tem...')
#2 ee/legacy/database/DB_driver.php(175): CI_DB_driver->simple_query('UPDATE `exp_tem...')
#3 ee/legacy/database/DB_active_rec.php(1388): CI_DB_driver->query('UPDATE `exp_tem...')
#4 ee/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Update.php(116): CI_DB_active_record->update('templates')
#5 ee/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Update.php(93): ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Update->actOnGateway(Object(ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\SyntheticGateway), Object(ExpressionEngine\Model\Template\Template))
#6 ee/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Update.php(46): ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Update->doWork(Object(ExpressionEngine\Model\Template\Template))
#7 ee/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/DataStore.php(275): ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Update->run()
#8 ee/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/DataStore.php(240): ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\DataStore->runQuery('Update', Object(ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder))
#9 ee/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Builder.php(71): ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\DataStore->updateQuery(Object(ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder))
#10 ee/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Model.php(358): ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder->update()
#11 ee/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/FileSyncedModel.php(109): ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Model->save()
#12 [internal function]: ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\FileSyncedModel->onAfterLoad()
#13 ee/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Model.php(826): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 ee/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Result.php(70): ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Model->emit('afterLoad')
#15 ee/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Builder.php(63): ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Result->all()
#16 ee/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Design/AbstractDesign.php(437): ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder->all()
#17 ee/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Design/Design.php(93): ExpressionEngine\Controller\Design\AbstractDesign->buildTableFromTemplateQueryBuilder(Object(ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder))
#18 ee/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Design/Design.php(27): ExpressionEngine\Controller\Design\Design->manager()
#19 [internal function]: ExpressionEngine\Controller\Design\Design->index()
#20 ee/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(257): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 ee/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(113): ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->runController(Array)
#22 ee/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.php(161): ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->run(Object(ExpressionEngine\Core\Request))
#23 public/admin.php(147): require_once('...')
#23 public/admin.php(147): require_once('...')
```

Comment: Is this on the same server?  Or a new one?  Shooting from the hip (without the full picture).  We usually see something along these signs when there's emojis in a template, and the DB doesn't have the proper CHARACTER SET to support it.

Comment: Hi Tom, the issue was the emojis in the template! Thanks!

Comment: Can either if you add this as an answer for this question?

Comment: Hi Anna, wanted to accept Tom's answer, but can't see the colored checkmark next to the answer to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this on the same server? Or a new one? Shooting from the hip (without the full picture). We usually see something along these signs when there's emojis in a template, and the DB doesn't have the proper CHARACTER SET to support it.